OpenConnect VPN сервер не работает
Всем здравствуйте, имеется vpn сервер open connect сеть которого "192.168.2.0", который слушает порт "5123" на домене "vpn.example.com", а также route "192.168.2.0/24" через шлюз "example.com". При попытке захода на "https://vpn.example.com:5123" возвращается xml:
<config-auth client="vpn" type="auth-request">
<version who="sg">0.1(1)</version>
<auth id="main">
<message>Please enter your username.</message>
<form method="post" action="/auth">
<input type="text" name="username" label="Username:"/>
</form>
</auth>
</config-auth>

Но при попытке подключения к этому VPN через протокол "Cisco AnyConnect" сначало все идет хорошо, подключается, дальше просит логин, а после этого ошибка: не удалось подключиться. С чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?
Заранее спасибо)
